# Split brackets into columns - SSMS

Tags: t-sql, ssms-2014

I have a string value [a1.1]+[a2.1]+[a3.1]+[a4.1]

I need the string value within each bracket to show in a single column but have no idea how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated

An example of the output  that i need is below

a1.1
a2.1
a3.1
a4.1

Answer (score 0):

Using [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) you could do this:

```
SELECT ItemNumber = s.ItemNumber-1, Item = SUBSTRING(s.item,0,CHARINDEX(']',s.item))
FROM   dbo.DelimitedSplit8K('[a1.1]+[a2.1]+[a3.1]+[a4.1]','[') AS s
WHERE  s.ItemNumber > 1;
```

**Returns:**

```
ItemNumber  Item
----------- -------
1           a1.1
2           a2.1
3           a3.1
4           a4.1
```